# LINQ - Grouping a List<T> by a property which is also a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

```
public class Product {
    public List<DateTime> FailureDates { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<Product>` and then I'm trying to do a grouping based on a `List<DateTime>` for use in a chart.  The grouping is supposed to be based on the Year of the DateTime object.  So I would want the end result to look something like:

**Total Failures by Year**

2012: 1,

2011: 5,

2010: 3

... and so on.

I originally had this working before the DateTime object became a list with the following code:

```
return Json.Encode(Products.Where(s => s.FailureDate != DateTime.MinValue).GroupBy(s => s.FailureDate.Year).Select(s => new { Year = s.Key.ToString(), FailureCount = s.Count() }).ToArray());
```

But, now that DateTime is a List so I'm not sure how to go about grouping it.  I am thinking a merge needs to occur for this to work, so maybe the LINQ code will just end up being too messy and I would be better of using a non-LINQ solution (e.g. iterating through my products and then iterating through my dates and building out a dictionary to keep track of the counts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would work for you.

```
var query = from p in Products
            from f in p.FailureDates 
            where f != DateTime.MinValue
            group f by f.Year into g
            select new
            {
              Year = g.Key.ToString(),
              FailureCount = g.Count(),
            }
```

Or to use your example, just add a SelectMany on Products like this

```
return Json.Encode(Products.SelectMany(p => p.FailureDates)
                           .Where(s => s != DateTime.MinValue)
                           .GroupBy(s => s.Year)
                           .Select(s => new { Year = s.Key.ToString(), FailureCount = s.Count() }).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples, appreciated.